# Happily necessary condition for lamentable hypothetical result

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice, syntax

How would you translate this famous English sentence into Latin? I don't think I've come across the Latin grammatical conventions to express this kind of causal relation between the protasis and apodosis.

> All that is necessary for evil to triumph is that good men do nothing.

I'll post an answer of my own, in hope of constructive criticism.

Answer (score 5):

To pile on to the suggestions so far, here is a possibility that radically alters the structure of the sentence but hopefully captures some of Latin's epigrammatic power:

> Desidia bonorum, victoria malorum.

or perhaps:

> In bonorum desidia, malorum victoria.

Comment: This takes several steps away from the original structure and is closer to "laziness of the good means victory for the bad", but in some situations it's for the best.

Comment: Nice! I like the second option better as the order of phrases reflects the causal relationship.

Comment: These are my favorite so far. Unlike my feeble attempt, they actually sound like something one would come across in an ancient work – one of Seneca's tragedies, perhaps. If I had to change one thing about each, I'd reverse the order of the phrases in the first and _possibly_ use _ex_/_e_ instead of _in_ in the second (but I think I see why you've chosen _in_).

Comment: Pile away! I especially like the radical change in structure, making strong use of Latin's grammar and vocabulary.

Comment: @cnread Thanks! I like your suggestion for the first one and agree that *ex* also works well in the second. There are some cool opportunities for chiasma as well, e.g. "bonorum desidia victoria malorum"

Answer (score 4):

I'd do something like this:

> malum ut superet, unum hoc necesse est, cessare homines bonos.

As for a critique of your versions (since you asked):

- You're absolutely right to avoid *triumpho*, for the reason that you gave.
- For the first version specifically, and your notes about it:

  - The conclusion of the *satis est* clause is *(ut) homines probi nihil faciant*, not *ut malum praevaleat*. The clause *ut malum praevaleat* is a purpose (adverbial) clause, whereas *satis est* needs a noun/noun clause to define what's 'enough.' Here, it's enough **that good men do nothing**.
  - I believe (but could be mistaken) that *praevaleo* means more 'to **have** the upper hand' than 'to **gain** the upper hand,' which, I agree with you, is the sense that's required here. If this is the case, the form of *vinco* in your second version is preferable.
  - *satis est non magis quam* just doesn't work. At the very least, I think that you'd have to change *non magis* to something like *nihil aliud* and move it in front of *satis* (though *nihil aliud satis est quam* still doesn't feel quite right to me). You might even consider whether *satis est* needs anything of this sort at all: *satis est (ut) nihil faciant homines probi* works perfectly well and gains force from its directness.
- For the second version:

  - *quod* might work – but to introduce the **second** subordinate clause (*nihil faciant homines probi*, the noun clause that defines what's 'enough'), not the first. That first clause really does want to be a purpose construction. (Note: I haven't checked whether there are any ancient examples of *satis est* + *quod*.)
  - I don't think you can get away with leaving out *satis est* here. For ellipsis to work, the left-out words have to readily supplied from context or common sense.
  - See above for *non magis quam*.

Answer (score 4):

As in @Brianpck's suggestion, a Roman would have been more direct, more concise. I'd have put it as *Quo minus agunt boni, eo plus floret malum*.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest something lighter, as the suggestions so far feel a bit too heavy to my taste.
The key step to me was to replace "doing nothing" with a noun.
(I realize that you might see this as a non-answer, as my solution for translating your sentence structure to Latin is to not use this structure at all.)
The most compact translation I could come up with is this:

> *Nulla re nisi ignavia proborum vincit improbum.*
>   The evil wins only through the laziness of good men.

The instrumental ablative gives a different tone than what you were after.
If this tone does not feel suitable, I suggest adding and *opus est* structure.
I still like the *nihil nisi* phrase.

> *Nulla re nisi ignavia proborum opus est, ut vincat improbum.*
>   Nothing but the laziness of good men is needed for evil to win.

You can adjust the translation by choosing other words.
I was not sure if I should use *otium*, *socordia*, or *sopor* instead of *ignavia*.
I prefer using *improbum* for "evil", not because it is the best translation in itself, but because it contrasts with *proborum*.

I originally had *nullo* (as an ablative of *nihil* or *nullum*), but I changed to *nulla re* for clarity.
One could also use the ablative *nihilo*.

Comment: I can't help but read *nullo* as "no one" instead of "nothing," which makes it hard to see the ablative of means. Do you know if "nullum" alone can mean the same as "nihil"?

Comment: @brianpck True, *nullo* looks more like *nemo* than *nihil* here. Perhaps I should have used *nulla re* instead. I thought I could use *nullo* as the ablative of *nihil*, but it doesn't seem to work well here.

Comment: *Nihil/nihilum* does have a regular ablative *nihilo*, btw.

Comment: @TKR Good point! I have only rarely come across that form, so I tend to forget it. I added a remark.

Comment: Changing the structure is good! A big part of learning another language is letting your thoughts form within the natural structures of that language rather than trying to map grammatical structures directly from one's own.

Answer (score 1):

> Ut malum praevaleat, satis est non magis quam homines probos nihil facere.

I've usually seen **satis est ut** in constructions where the point is to say "It is enough to do *X.*" I really don't want to say "Doing evil is enough" or lead a listener down a grammatical garden path that suggests that. So I'm not sure about **ut** here. Or does **ut** come across ironically, amplifying the meaning, since normally it would indicate an intended result?

Here's a variation:

> Quod mali vincant, non magis quam nihil faciant homines probi.

I actually think **quod** is wrong here, but I dug through some grammatical stuff and couldn't settle it.

I'm not sure if it's comprehensible to make a subjunctive clause the object of **non magis quam**, but there it is. I find **quam** the single most confusing word in Latin. The infinitive seems more natural to me, but that might only be because I have a lot more experience with acc+inf.

This one is a chiasmus, trying to put emphasis on the contrast between **probi** and **mali** by delaying it until the end. I'm thinking that contrasting **improbi** and **probi** would sound lame.

I'm thinking here that **non magis quam** is clear enough to drop **satis est**, and omitting the main verb even adds some bite.

I went through a lot of possibilities for a noun for "evil", and none seemed to suggest a force in the world—bad, power-seeking, destructive people in the world. After all that, I'm thinking that the adjective **malum** might actually fit best. Without a noun, I'm think that the adjective means "evil in the world" or, in the plural, "evil men". Hopefully it's not misread or misheard as **mālum** or the other senses of **mali**, which would make the sentence ridiculous.

**Triumpho** is of course another option for the first verb, but I'm thinking that in Latin it suggests the triumphal procession rather than the victory. I'm thinking that **praevaleo** suggests getting the edge, the upper hand, taking over—which would be perfect.